# Laravel Query Builder - Error for using NOW() and DateFormat

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a MySQL table like this-

[image]

And a query builder of Laravel like this-

```
    $baseQuery = DB::table('webinars')
        ->select(
                    'id',
                    'title',
                    'description',
                    'hosts',
                    DB::raw('concat(DATE_FORMAT(starts_on,"%d %b %Y %h:%i %p), " ", timezone) as starts'),
                    'duration',
                    'created_at'
                )
        ->where('user_id', '=', $user_ID)
        ->where('starts_on >= NOW()');
```

So, I am getting error for this 2 line-

```
        DB::raw('concat(DATE_FORMAT(starts_on,"%d %b %Y %h:%i %p), " ", timezone) as starts')
```

And

```
        ->where('starts_on >= NOW()');
```

Error is -

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a double quote after date mask:

> DB::raw('concat(DATE_FORMAT(starts_on, "%d %b %Y %h:%i %p), " ",
>   timezone) as starts')

Should be:

```
DB::raw('concat(DATE_FORMAT(starts_on, "%d %b %Y %h:%i %p"), " ", timezone) as starts')
```

> ->where('starts_on >= NOW()');

you can use:

`whereRaw('starts_on >= NOW()')` or

`where('starts_on', '>=', new DateTime('today'))`